Why do chanting malas have 108+1 beads?
I have often heard that the number 108 has a special significance in the Vedic culture; when mantras are chanted using beads, it is done in a cycle of 108 times. And when 108 times are completed, the sumeru bead is not crossed and the mala is flipped. I wish to know the significance behind this.
Is there any scriptural reference about this? Has any prominent acharya commented on it?
